# Xbox One + RAID + SSD = Insane?

Tags: xbox-one

After doing some research, it appears that the XBox One benefits from [faster hard drives for load times](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2015-faster-hard-drives-boost-xbox-one-fallout-4-performance).

And, based on more research, it appears that, despite SSD drives impressive capabilities, the performance is [drastically improved in a RAID 0 configuration](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2365767/feed-your-greed-for-speed-by-installing-ssds-in-raid-0.html).

The question is, would this configuration make sense in a real world scenario?  I suspect that there would be some fundamental maximum limit (not the USB 3.0 limit, but inside the XBox One architecture) and that the benefit of using this configuration would only provide some incremental improvement in load times.  However, all of the articles I've read so far have not seemed to show that they have hit any such limit.

Has anyone tried anything like this that would have some insight?

Comment: sure would be nice if someone would say why they didn't like the question so I could fix it.  :-(

Comment: Make it clearer you want to use a external NAS connected with usb, I think that's why some people might have downvoted

Answer (score 3):

Using the usb port of the Xbox one to hook up a NAS configured with Raid 0 hard disks would work but, at that point, why not just change the hard disk inside the XBox one for a single SSD (of at least 500Gb) since for the price of a NAS + Disks, a good 500Gb SSD ([like the samsung evo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OBRE5UE)) is even cheaper, the 1Tb would stay in the same price range as [the NAS you linked](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007B61GVI) + 2 disks.

The difference of raid 0 wouldn't be that better than a single, internally linked SSD.

If you take a look at [iFixit guide to replace a xbox one hard drive](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Xbox+One+Hard+Drive+Replacement/36771), you'll notice how there's no way to connect two hard drives to the xbox one (there seems to only have 1 sata data and 1 sata power connector on the xbox one board), making a raid configuration almost impossible. I doubt that the board firmware and/or OS of the xbox one would support a raid configuration.

There might be ways to get it to work with 1 sata connector and making the raid external but that's something I doubt would improve the read/write speeds as much as an actual hardware, or even software, raid 0 configuration possible in most PC. Not only that, the needed software and hardware to make that happen might just slow it too much to be worth it.

Comment: Right, no, I'm not suggesting breaking open the box, but using the USB 3.0 connection and hooking up a NAS RAID box... like this one:  http://amzn.com/B007B61GVI

Answer (score 2):

Raid 0 with 4 hdds on my XBONE improved performance by about 30% (at most) for me over the internal drive. I am seeing about the same with a single high end SSD. RAID SSD is too rich for my blood, but I'll happily test it out if anyone wants to fund it.

Answer (score 0):

RAID0 on SSD is a waste because its on ONE USB only meaning thrughput is STILL restricted to 5Gbps - IOPS maybe better but unsure n probanly not

RAID0 on HDD is worth it cos they max abput 190Mbps (1.9Gbps) so two wou;d give you near SSD performance

may aswell get a 2Tb SSD and insert inside the Xbox as on USB its throttled 20% (5Gbps vs 6Gbps)

Comment: The Xbone is limited to Sata 2 so the USB 3 would actuall be faster.